# Every view or component that uses pagination has 3 default properties. Best way to avoid duplicating these properties on every component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, pagination

Every one of my Vue.js components has the following 3 properties used to track the items:

```js
data(){
    return {
        currentPage: 1,
        totalItems: null,
        totalPages: null,
    }
}
```

Which means I literally copy-paste these 3 properties on every component which has to use pagination. I know this is definitely not the most optimal way to do this. I was wondering if I use should mixins for this, or maybe some other implementation?

```html
<template lang="html">
    <div class="home">
        <Product v-for='product in products' :product='product'></Product>
        <Pagination :currentPage="currentPage" :totalPages="totalPages" @setCurrentPage="setCurrentPage"></Pagination>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Product from '../components/Product'
import Pagination from '../components/Pagination'

export default {
    components: {
        Product,
        Pagination
    },
    data(){
        return {
            currentPage: 1,
            products: null,
            totalItems: null,
            totalPages: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getProducts(){
            let response = await axios.get('/products?page=' + this.currentPage)
            this.products = response.data.products
            this.totalItems = response.data.totalItems
            this.totalPages = response.data.totalPages
        },
        setCurrentPage(page){
            this.currentPage = page
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getProducts()
    }
}
</script>
```

Pagination component:

```html
<template lang="html">
    <div class="pagination">
        <div v-for="page in pages">
            <div class="page" :class="{ active: page == currentPage}" @click="setCurrentPage(page)">{{ page }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ["totalPages", "currentPage"],
    methods: {
        setCurrentPage(page){
            this.$emit("setCurrentPage", page);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        pages() {
            const numShown = Math.min(5, this.totalPages);
            let first = this.currentPage - Math.floor(numShown / 2);
            first = Math.max(first, 1);
            first = Math.min(first, this.totalPages - numShown + 1);
            return [...Array(numShown)].map((k,i) => i + first);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Vuex would probably be ideal

Comment: Make a reusable component instead and bind to events if necessary so you're not tracking these properties.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'm not sure what does that mean exactly. By reusable component, do you mean that the component should take these properties as props or something?

Comment: No, I think that your need to bind these same variables to whatever requires them is indicative of an anti pattern. Why does the parent component implementing your paginator require they define these properties? What does the parent need from these? Can you share some code?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I've uploaded my home view which renders products and their pagination.

Comment: You could save yourself two of those `data` vars by making `totalItems` and `totalPages` `computed` properties. In theory, they always depend on and should change with your item list, so there's no real reason you need to store them separately.

Comment: @zcoop98 Can you show me how?

Comment: @Bobimaru Sure! Let me pull something together real quick. Are there other keys in `response.data`? Or just `products`, `totalItems`, and `totalPages`?